# SCNParticleSystem not showing in scene

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am using SceneKit to render a 3D Egg (with Vuforia AR tech). I am adding some particle fire effects when the egg is augmented. When I attach the particle system to the Egg node it appears, but it is 'in' the egg and causes a bunch of nasty rendering artefacts.

If I create an empty node and add the particle system to it, then it doesn't appear at all.

The position of the node is 0,0,0 and yet I don't see a thing. The particle system is looping so I should see it.

I was wondering if the node needs to have some kind of geometry attached for it to work, so I also added a sphere geom. Still doesn't show.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It might be the blending mode you're using for the particles. Check what it is, and try some of the other blending modes. And make allowances for this product being in beta... SceneKit and SpriteKit have had bugs in their particles for several generations...

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the SceneKit view is part of a Vuforia Augmented Reality view. So it is a camera feed texture as the background.

Comment: You had any luck getting them to be at all visible?

Comment: I'm going to do an experiment today. Will add ParticleSystem in Xcode's IB Scene tool and see if that works.